# Using IdentityServer4 for a subscription based API

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

In the current situation, we use IdentityServer4 in our API for Authentication and Authorization.

We would like to protect some endpoints within the API with a subscription-based process. So some endpoints can only be called when a user has the role "Subscriber". The authorization based on the role is working. But our question lays within the authentication.

**What way/flow can we use to make it as easy as possible to authenticate on the API as a customer, using IdentityServer4?**

Example: Stripe and Google both use permanent private keys to Authenticate the user. Should we also implement something like this? And if so, how can we achieve this with IdentityServer4?

Comment: If request requires authorization, OAuth 2.0 is best option. Using API keys is mostly for public APIs. [google ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/authorizing).

Comment: I don't understand "What way/flow can we use to make it as easy as possible to authenticate on the API as a customer, using IdentityServer4?" part. Can you add more explanation in the question?